# How to find the most derived subclass of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

IDK if the question helps, but in C++ is it possible to do the following:

```cpp
PinAbstract* pin1 = new ValuedPin<int>();
ValuedPin<int>* pin2 = new ValuedPin<int>();
std::cout << (get_most_derived_subclass(pin1) == get_most_derived_subclass(pin2)) << std::endl;
//OUTPUT should be:
1 <- Since both are at most ValuedPin<int>*'s, even if pin1 is declared as PinAbstract.
```

Where PinAbstract is a superclass to ValuedPin. `typeid` doesn't work for pointers and values, since for pin1 it returns PinAbstract.

Comment: What do you mean by "typeid doesn't work for pointers"?

Comment: Well, not specifically for pointers, but `typeid` returns PinAbstract* for the example above for pin1.

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but does `PinAbstract` have at least one virtual method?

Comment: C++ does not really work this way. C++ is not Java, Python, or Perl.

Comment: @PaulSanders, actually yes `PinAbstract` does have a virtual method, does that prevent the `typeid` from getting the subclass?

Comment: @ChrisGeorge Have you tried indirecting through the pointer?

Comment: @eerorika [I just did](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H9z7ziSDLSEBFcDg) and that works.

Comment: @ChrisGeorge No, it's necessary.  But see eerorika's comment.  He has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @eerorika By redirecting do you mean dereferencing the pointer because that WORKS!!

Comment: @ChrisGeorge Yes. That is what indirecting through a pointer means.

Comment: So the answer is that the most derived class of the pointer `pin1` is `PinAbstract*`, while the most derived class of the pointed-to-object `*pin1` is `ValuedPin<int>`? Does that count as a typo? Even if it's a typo, could an answer help future readers?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, what you are asking is not possible, as there is nothing like `get_most_derived_subclass()` in C++.

However, for polymorphic types (types with `virtual` methods), you can use `dynamic_cast` to determine whether or not a given object implements a given type, eg:

```
PinAbstract* pin1 = ...;
std::cout << (dynamic_cast<ValuedPin<int>*>(pin1) != NULL) << std::endl;
```